# I am not able to install Microsoft identityandaccess.vsix tool extension for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

When I install extension `identityandaccess.vsix`, it's throwing the following error:

```
5/21/2014 3:15:04 PM - Searching for applicable products...
5/21/2014 3:15:04 PM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013
5/21/2014 3:15:04 PM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2013
5/21/2014 3:15:04 PM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013
5/21/2014 3:15:04 PM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Shell (Integrated)
5/21/2014 3:15:04 PM - Found installed product - Global Location
5/21/2014 3:15:04 PM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
```

Comment: You most probably have Visual Studio Express edition, which doesn't support extensions.

Comment: No I m using vs 2013 ultimate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure this is the extension that you are trying to install and it is for VS 2012 only.  If you read the Q & A section you will see several other people wanting the extension updated to support VS 2013.  Sounds like you are out of luck.

[Indentity and Access Tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e21bf653-dfe1-4d81-b3d3-795cb104066e)

Comment: Thanks Scott, I got it the following things from Q & A Section.
In VS2013 we added support for claims-based identity directly into the ASP.NET project creation experience (see http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2013/06/26/improved-windows-azure-active-directory-integration-with-asp-net-amp-visual-studio.aspx), hence there are no plans of porting the Identity and Access tool to VS2013.

Answer (score 0):

In VS2013 we added support for claims-based identity directly into the ASP.NET project creation experience (see http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2013/06/26/improved-windows-azure-active-directory-integration-with-asp-net-amp-visual-studio.aspx), hence there are no plans of porting the Identity and Access tool to VS2013.

Comment: your link has moved.